# How do I enable someone who has been disabled?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm doing a little sidequest for farkas/the companions and I disabled Farkas when trying to disable an enemy. I accidently lost Farkas' ID. I looked up the ID on the Elder Scroll's Wiki and when I tried his ID's along with "enable" nothing happend. This is really worrying me and I can't find any forums with the answer so I hoped that you guys could help. Thanks.

Comment: NPCs have two IDs—a BaseID and a RefID. Which did you use?

Comment: I used the BaseID

Comment: Use the RefID. That's what targeted commands take. (The BaseID is only for modding purposes.)

Comment: Thank's I'll try that EDIT: It just says invalid object ID

Answer (score 4):

```
prid 0001A693
enable
```

`prid` selects an NPC by its refID, you can find other NPCs' refIDs on the [UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Farkas).